# Python, how to get the params of an xsl stylesheet?

Tags: python, regex, xslt

I want to get the params of an `xsl` file which is used to transform an `xml` file to a `csv` file.
I especially want to get this line:

```
<xsl:param name="sep" select="','"/>
```

What I've tried:

```
 with open(file, "r") as file:
    content = file.readlines()
    regex = re.compile(r"""<xsl:param +name *= *"[0-9A-Za-z]+" +select *= *"\\'.\\'"/>""")
    for line in content:
        print(line)
        match = regex.match(line)
        if match:
            pass
            # do something
```

I tried different regular expressions but nothing worked.
I'm using python 3.6 and `lxml` to transform it.

**EDIT** the xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:param name="sep" select="','"/>
  <xsl:param name="test" select="','"/>
  <xsl:param name="test2" select="','"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">title,artist,country,company,price,year
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
<xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;', title, '&quot;', $sep, '&quot;', artist, '&quot;', $sep, '&quot;',
country, '&quot;', $sep, '&quot;', company, '&quot;', $sep, price, $sep, year, '&#10;')"/>
</xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Why not use an xml parser? What if the separator is something like `&amp;`? Would your regex parse that correctly?

Comment: Could you provide the whole file for testing purposes?

Comment: @Frynio I added the xsl file

Comment: @Aran-Fey i use an xml parser but i need to change the param in the xsl file to create the csv file with different seperators. I don't want to cover all seperators but with a single letter it should work.

Comment: Modifying the XSLT is not really the right approach if you want to use a different parameter. You need to read up about how to set parameters when your perform the transform. Perhaps this helps... https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#stylesheet-parameters

Comment: @TimC yes your right, but I need the name of the parameters in the xsl file to transform the xml file. Maybe my explenation was a bit bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `xml` parser. Like this:

Suppose your file is `test.xsl`. Then you could do:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('test.xsl')
root = tree.getroot()
match = [c.attrib for c in root if 'param' in c.tag]
```

Then `match` looks like this:

```
>>> print(match)
[{'name': 'sep', 'select': "','"}, {'name': 'test', 'select': "','"}, {'name': 'test2', 'select': "','"}]
```

I assume, that you don't need the whole line, just the attributes between `<>` tags. Having those attributes will allow you to create the `csv` file you need.

Comment: Thank you, excactly what i was looking for.